# How do I properly use the cinch-straps that came with my daypack?

Tags: backpacks

I just purchased a daypack to stuff inside my larger backpack while travelling.  It came with cinch-straps but I'm not sure of the proper way to use them (if there is one).  The daypack is  a [North Face Verto 26](http://www.thenorthface.com/catalog/sc-gear/verto-26.html)

[image: Picture of a daypack]

Clearly, they go through the loops on the pack, but I'm not sure how to anchor them (the cinch-straps themselves are closed loops).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per The North Face Customer Service:

> Each strap (not bungee, sorry about that) should have a barrel on one end followed by an [overhand knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/overhand/) holding the two ends of the strap.  Simply undo the knot, depress the button on the barrel and un-thread one end of the strap.  Thread through loops as desired, re-thread through barrel, tie off ends using a [2 strand overhand knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/doubleoverhand/)

Comment: Is there a "best" way to thread them I wonder?  like shoe-laces is probably the most common right?

Comment: lol, in hindsight I guess undoing the knots seems sort of obvious, no wonder I couldn't figure out how to anchor them.  Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: I suppose I could have also asked customer service myself, but then I wouldn't have had the chance to try out the fancy new great outdoors SE!

Comment: @Ryley: Their suggestion is to adjust the lacing to your content. On their video they briefly show two different options. I was surprise they didn't have instructions on their website. Perhaps a generic question on the topic would generate more interesting answers.

Answer (score 3):

I have a small summit pack that has loops on each side of the backpack, which your's seems to have as well. My pack advertised those for "securing overloads," meaning you can drape stuff that doesn't fit inside (like a rope), over the pack before you close the lid and secure it with the straps to each side of the pack. On each side of the pack I thread a loop, pass the stap over the item I want to secure, thread a loop on that side of the item, and repeat until I run out of loops. Then I do the other side.